# Understand why this is a joke

Tags: перевод, значения, выражения

I can read Russian, and understand mostly what is written here:

[image: https://cs14.pikabu.ru/post_img/2021/12/01/10/1638378131199363687.jpg]

But what I fail to see is why this is a joke? What makes it funny?
I am interested what am I missing in understanding in this joke that would make it funny?

Like why is the name of cheese: `Bri` funny?

Or name of the champagne: `briut`, funny?

Answer (score 6):

This is a rhetorical device known as [alliteration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration).

*Бри* means "brie", a type of French cheese. *Брют* means "brut", a type of champagne. These words are not funny in and of themselves, but they do make the alliteration work.

Being funny is a very subjective thing. This particular alliteration is not very funny to me personally, but I can see how it can be to other people.

Comment: Sorry forgot to finish sign up, but thanks, your answer makes sense

Answer (score 6):

Alliteration is fun when you try to read it out loud quickly. You're sure to mix up and mess up the words, and that's funny. We have lots of tongue-twisters based on this principle.

Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку.

На дворе трава, на траве дрова.

Шит колпак не по-колпаковски. Надо колпак переколпаковать, перевыколпаковать.

Try to say them quickly and you'll at least smile.